# ajax postback with php

Tags: php, ajax

i have a form field excepting text.  i use ajax and php to save the text into mysql and post back the the submitted text on the page without a refresh.

Example: "Here's My Text Example"

The returned text to the page displays as "Here///'s My Text Example"

if i do a stripslashes($_POST['txt']) to display the text i still get this "Here/'s My Text Example"

How do i resolve this so all the /// come out of the returned text?

Answer (score 1):

Is magic quotes enabled? Try put this in your php code:

`ini_set ('magic_quotes_gpc', 0);`

Comment: I added this code to my php and the result is the same. still one / displays on the post back

Comment: do you use stripslashes ($_POST['txt']) ?

Comment: i did use stripslashes it removes 2 of the 3 / (slashes) leaving one.